# How to manage USB powering for sleep mode?

Tags: 12.04, usb, keyboard, mouse, power-management

How to disable USB powering for sleep mode while on AC? Settings for each controller or each device would be nice, but I'm glad to see even a global setting.

If on AC, after my Ubuntu turns asleep it leave an USB hub (without external power to hub) powered which makes a mouse and a keyboard dragging current (well, not much but furthermore LED lights are annoying). It is not needed since I'm not going to use keyboard or mouse when system is sleeping and not reasonable since no mouse nor keyboard usage wakes the system up.

In asleep mode while not on AC, hub is powered off (desired situation!) so I'm doing a lot of plugging in and out (not desired situation!).

Comment: As far as I know this is managed by your system's BIOS/UEFI. In both my Dell and HP machines I have a setting for exactly that.

Comment: HP 655: I see no related options in BIOS (F10). There is UEFI boot, but not many more settings, nothing advanced at least. How do You access that?

Comment: I have that option too.  Did you see if there is a BIOS update for your system?

Comment: Already the latest F.26 installed. This is a notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution, but kind of a move forward.

By installing `powertop` and changing its' `tunables` I've managed to reason keyboard powering for a sleep mode - now it wakes the system up on key press.

Comment: Since I have the only power key under the lid on my laptop and working on an external monitor, it is useful, yet I'm interested in totally disabling (poweroff) all USBs for a sleep mode.